# Redirect from removed page htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect `https://example.com/?lang=eng` to `https://example.com/english.html`

The problem is that the page `https://example.com/?lang=eng` doesn't exist anymore, the site was written in php and it was changed to pure html css.

An ordinary redirect like this doesn't work!

```
Redirect 301 https://example.com/?lang=eng https://example.com/english.html
```

It is important to redirect this page because I have a lot of external links pointing to it.

Comment: found the solution !

Comment: Need  to use RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=rus$